# Check whether the three vectors form a triangle

Tags: vectors

> Check whether the three vectors $2\hat i + 2 \hat j + 3 \hat k, -3 \hat i + 3 \hat j + 2\hat k , 3\hat i + 4\hat k$ form a triangle or not.

Attempt:

$\vec{AB} = - 5\hat i + \hat j - \hat k$
And $\vec{AC} = \hat i + \hat k -2\hat j$

Therfore they form a triangle as AB and AC are not co-linear.

But textbook says,

> For a triangle $\vec a + \vec b + \vec c = 0$
>
> But for the given three vectors the sum is not zero so they do not
>   form a triangle.

I don't understand the error in my attempt and the way the textbook finds the right answer. Please explain the concepts involved.

Why is $\vec a + \vec b + \vec c = 0?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a confusion between a triangle based on points and a triangle given by side vectors.

Your interpretation of the given data is that those are three points $A, B,C$.

The solution seems to indicate that the given data represents three vectors. You’re asked if those three vectors can be the sides of a triangle.

Comment: Why is $\vec a + \vec b + \vec c= 0 ?$

Comment: If the given vectors represent the edges of a triangle, the path through those three vectors has to be closed. Hence the relationship $\vec a + \vec b + \vec c= \vec 0$.

Answer (score 0):

The textbook doesn't treat these vectors as points in space but as "arrows"/line segments and asks whether those three arrows form a triangle.